# How to detect chinese/japanese characters in file name?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to detect if the file name received from other apps contains chinese/japanese characters in iphone?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to be a bit more specific to get good answers. If the string is not an NSString, you need to decode it first, using the encoding that is appropriate. For example, use the NSString "stringWithUTF8String" for decoding UTF-8 encoded strings.
Once you have an NSString, you can use "characterAtIndex:" to iterate through the characters, and check whether they contain any Chinese and/or Japanese code points.
See the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) standard for these code points.

BTW, you should change the title of the question because you are not interested whether the file names are English